# How to fix a group and show related user in drop down?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have to try a fix a group  related users show in drop down menu  . I am not sure but they have done via two possible method:

1. using group id
2. using group name

so can  you tell me how to done this because i don't have any idea for this .

my group are base on res.groups and related users come from res.users

field are show below

`group_id = fields.one2many('res,groups', Group),`

`user_id = fields.one2many('res.users', Team)`

and my **group id** = 33 and my **group name** = Team Member

Comment: Issue solved ..

Comment: Please, explain how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello my problem is solved

> ```
> def _get_default_esc(self):
> print "yes:", 33 
> return 33 
> 'group_id' : fields.many2one('res.groups',"Group",change_default=True,def‌​ault=_get_default_es‌​c),
> ```